# Code duplication in a module methods of class and instance levels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have Memoize module, that provides methods for caching of class and instance methods.

```
module Memoize
  def instance_memoize(*methods)
    memoizer = Module.new do
      methods.each do |method|
        define_method method do
          @_memoized_results ||= {}

          if @_memoized_results.include? method
            @_memoized_results[method]
          else
            @_memoized_results[method] = super()
          end
        end
      end
    end

    prepend memoizer
  end

  def class_memoize(*methods)
    methods.each do |method|
      define_singleton_method method do
        @_memoized_results ||= {}

        if @_memoized_results.include? method
          @_memoized_results[method]
        else
          @_memoized_results[method] = super()
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This is an example of how I use it:

```
class Foo
  extend Memoize

  instance_memoize :instance_method1, :instance_method2
  class_memoize    :class_method1, :class_method2

  ...
end
```

Please advice how to avoid code duplication in this module.

Comment: Offtopic: memoization tipically means storing the results for particular sets of inputs. This means that you should also take the arguments passed to the methods into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One might define a [lambda](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Proc.html):

```
λ = lambda do
  @_memoized_results ||= {}

  if @_memoized_results.include? method
    @_memoized_results[method]
  else
    @_memoized_results[method] = super()
  end
end
```

And. then:

```
define_method method, &λ
```

Please be aware of an ampersand in front of `λ`, it is used to notice `define_method` about it’s receiving a block, rather than a regular argument.

---

I did not get what failed with this approach on your side, but here is a bullet-proof version:

```
method_declaration = %Q{
  def %{method}
    @_memoized_results ||= {}

    if @_memoized_results.include? :%{method}
      @_memoized_results[:%{method}]
    else
      @_memoized_results[:%{method}] = super()
    end
  end
}

methods.each do |method|
  class_eval method_declaration % {method: method}
end
```

Comment: Thanks, you advised good approach, but it does not work, because I should pass "method" argument into lambda.  Thus I should invoke          "define_method method { lambda_template.call(method) }". In this case super() will invoke "call" method, that is incorrect.